# How to pick a multiple element from an embedded array in a MONGO document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql

I have a collection of documents and each document is of the following format:

```
{
    "file_id" : 2,
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "category" : "Auto1",
            "code_id" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "category" : "Auto2",
            "code_id" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "category" : "Auto3",
            "code_id" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "category" : "Workers1",
            "code_id" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "category" : "Workers2",
            "code_id" : 5
        }, 
        {
            "category" : "Workers3",
            "code_id" : 6
        }
   ]
}
```

Other similar documents are there and I want to query with `file_id` and `code_id` in data array.

The query should be like `file_id = 2, data.code_id = [2,4,5,8]`.
Result should contain the document with embedded documents (**multiple embedded documents**) which have `code_id` from the array specified above.

I tried

```
db.collectionName.findOne({
    "file_id": 1, 
    "data.code_id": { "$in": [2,4,5,8] }
}, { "file": 1, "data.$": 1 })
```

This returns **single embedded document** as written in official documentation but I want multiple embedded documents, what should I do?

**Required output**

```
{
    "file_id" : 2,
    "data" : [
        {
            "category" : "Auto2",
            "code_id" : 2
        },
        {
            "category" : "Workers1",
            "code_id" : 4
        },
        {
            "category" : "Workers2",
            "code_id" : 5
        }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Try db.collectionName.aggregate([{$unwind:"$data"},{$match:{"data.code_id": {"$in": [2,4,5,8]}}}]).

If this is what you want.

Comment: it gives multiple documents.
while i want that in one documents.

Comment: You mean you want all the results in one document?

Comment: embedded documents should be present in one document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best use the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** operator which allows you to select a subset of the array to return based on the specified condition. As for the condition, use the **[`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/#exp._S_setIsSubset)** operator which takes two arrays and returns true when the first array is a subset of the second, including when the first array equals the second array, and false otherwise.

```
var codeIds = [2,4,5,8];
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "data.code_id": { "$in": codeIds }, "file_id": 2 } },
    { 
        "$project": {
            "file_id": 1,
            "data": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": '$data',
                    "as": 'item',
                    "cond": { "$setIsSubset": [ ["$$item.code_id"], codeIds ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: `Thank you`.This is what i wanted.